# Unsure of what's wrong with my sorting algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, struct

I've been trying to use c-strings to perform a sort on inputted data. So far so good, except when it came to case 3 and 4, aka sorting and displaying sorted data, the output is not what was expected.
the output for displayed sorted data just gives me

0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
.
.
.
It's my first time working with c-strings and I'm still not too versed with the idea of structs. If anyone has an alternative method or knows what's the issue with my code for case 3/4, please let me know. Thank you

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct sPlayer {
    char lname[20];
    char fname[20];
    int birthmonth;
    int birthday;
    int birthyear;
};
int main()
{

    int choice;
    sPlayer players[10];
    sPlayer sortedData[10];

    while (true) {
        cout << "Choose an option: " << endl;
        cout << "1 - Input data, 2 - display original data, 3 - 
            sort data by last name,\n4 - display sorted data,
            5 - search by
                    last name,\n6 - display goodbye message and exit the program " << 
            endl;

        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:

            cout << "Enter data for 10 soccer players " << endl;
            cout << "Enter in order: Last name, first name,(as integers) birth month, birthday, birth year, ";
            cout << "separated by a space. Press [ENTER] to enter next player data. " << endl;

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cin >> players[i].lname;
                cin >> players[i].fname;
                cin >> players[i].birthmonth;
                cin >> players[i].birthday;
                cin >> players[i].birthyear;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Unsorted data: " << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                cout << players[i].lname << " "
                     << players[i].fname << " " << players[i].birthmonth;
                cout << " " << players[i].birthday << " " << players[i].birthyear << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            sortedData[10] = players[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {

                    if (strcmp(sortedData[i].lname, sortedData[j].lname) > 0) {
                        char tempLastName[20];
                        char tempFirstName[20];
                        int tempBirthmonth;
                        int tempBirthday;
                        int tempBirthyear;

                        strcpy(tempLastName, sortedData[i].lname);

                        strcpy(sortedData[i].lname, sortedData[j].lname);

                        strcpy(sortedData[j].lname, tempLastName);

                        strcpy(tempFirstName, sortedData[i].fname);

                        strcpy(sortedData[i].fname, sortedData[j].fname);

                        strcpy(sortedData[j].fname, tempFirstName);

                        tempBirthmonth = sortedData[i].birthmonth;

                        sortedData[i].birthmonth = sortedData[j].birthmonth;

                        sortedData[j].birthmonth = tempBirthmonth;

                        tempBirthday = sortedData[i].birthday;

                        sortedData[i].birthday = sortedData[j].birthday;

                        sortedData[j].birthday = tempBirthday;

                        tempBirthyear = sortedData[i].birthyear;

                        sortedData[i].birthyear = sortedData[j].birthyear;

                        sortedData[j].birthyear = tempBirthyear;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "Sorted data: " << endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                cout << sortedData[i].lname << " 
                                               " << sortedData[i].fname << "
                                               " << sortedData[i].birthmonth << "
                                               " 
                     << sortedData[i].birthday << " " << sortedData[i].birthyear << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
            break;

        case 5:
            char searchString[20];
            while (true) {
                cout << "Enter one or more 
                        starting letters of the last name(enter '//' to quit this option)
                    : " << endl;
                    cin
                    >> searchString;

                if (strcmp(searchString, "//")
                    == 0)
                    break;
                else {
                    int length = strlen(searchString);

                    strcat(searchString, "xx");
                    bool notFound = true;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        if (strncmp(players[i].lname, searchString, length) == 0) {
                            cout << players[i].lname << " " << players[i].fname << " " << players[i].birthmonth << " " << players[i].birthday << " " << players[i].birthyear << endl;

                            notFound = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (notFound) {
                        cout << "Not 
                                found." << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case 6:
            cout << "Good Bye " << endl;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Invalid Option , Try again" << endl;
        }
        if (choice == 6)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related, but if using input streams (`std::cin`), you should *always* check the stream state after input (you can group several read operations, but you can only assume valid data if the stream is still OK after last read). Be aware that user always might have entered invalid data (e. g. a string containing letters when asking for an integral value).

Comment: Much less complicated: `sPlayer tmp = sortedData[i]; sortedData[i] = sortedData[j]; sortedData[j] = tmp;`, which can even can be shortened just to `std::swap(sortedData[j], sortedData[j]);`...

Comment: `sortedData[10] = players[10];` is Undefined behavior because you're accessing past the end of the two arrays.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Just a few seconds faster than me... `[x]` represents just in one single case the size of an array: When you declare it. At any later point, it is accessing the array at some index. You now try to copy the 10th element (which doesn't exist), while the elements [0; 9] remain untouched. Off-topic again – why only 10 players? As far as I am aware, soccer teams consist of 11 ones...

Comment: Copying an array: Try `std::copy(players, players + sizeof(players)/sizeof(*players), sortedData);` – and [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is much more convenient than classic raw arrays in many respects.

Comment: @Aconcagua Another newbie confused by the fact that arrays start at zero in C++. For some reason this makes many newbies think that they have to declare an array with a **size** one less than they need. Even though the size of an array and the indexing scheme are completely independent issues.

Comment: @Aconcagua I've seen this several times recently. That strange thing is that the OP clearly understands that `array[x]` denotes a single element of an array, but for some again unknown reason some newbies think that they can also use the same notation to refer to the whole array. `sortedData[10] = players[10];` is clearly an attempt to copy the entire players array to the sortedData array.

Answer (score 0):

It is often better to split big problems into smaller ones. I recomend to use subfunctions.

And, you should use the C++ STL and algorithms. That is very helpful. You will see. Do not use plain arrays like `char lname[20]` or `sPlayer players[10];`. Please use STL container. They can grow and they can be resized. It may also reduce your copy effort drastically.

Use an Object Oriented approach. Data and methods should be in one class. A sPlayer knows how to print and how to read. So add those methods to your struct.

You should use algorithms. Like `std::copy`. This makes life easier.

The errors have already been mentioned in the comments under your post.

Please see a revised example (one possibility):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct sPlayer {
    // Data
    std::string lname;
    std::string fname;
    unsigned int birthmonth;
    unsigned int birthday;
    unsigned int birthyear;

    // Extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, sPlayer& sp) {
        return is >> sp.lname >> sp.fname >> sp.birthmonth >> sp.birthday >> sp.birthyear;
    }

    // Inserter operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const sPlayer& sp) {
        return os << sp.fname << ' ' << sp.lname << ' ' << sp.birthmonth << '/' << sp.birthday << '/' << sp.birthyear;
    }
};

constexpr int CmdInputData = 1;
constexpr int CmdDisplayOriginalData = 2;
constexpr int CmdSortByLastName = 3;
constexpr int CmdDisplaySortedData = 4;
constexpr int CmdSearchLastName = 5;
constexpr int CmdExit = 6;

// Read users choice. Check for valid data
int getMenuSelection()
{
    std::cout << "\n\nChoose an option:\n   1 - Input Data\n   2 - Display original data\n" <<
        "   3 - Sort data by last name\n   4 - Display sorted data\n   5 - Search by last name\n" <<
        "   6 - Exit the program\n\n --> ";

    // Here we will store the selection
    int selection{ 0 };
    // As long as there is no good selection, we will read a number
    bool noGoodSelection = true;
    while (noGoodSelection) {
        // Read selection
        std::cin >> selection;
        // Check if valid
        noGoodSelection = ((selection < CmdInputData) || (selection > CmdExit));
        // If not, show message and read again
        if (noGoodSelection) {
            std::cout << "Invalid Option , Try again" << '\n';
            std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore();
        }
    }
    return selection;
}


void enterSPlayerData(std::vector<sPlayer>& sp)
{
    // Ask, how many players we would like to register
    std::cout << "\n\nEnter soccer player data\n\nHow many player do you want to register: ";
    size_t numberOfPlayersToRegister{ 0 };
    std::cin >> numberOfPlayersToRegister;

    // Make space in vector for all the players
    sp.clear();
    sp.resize(numberOfPlayersToRegister);

    // Read all players
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfPlayersToRegister; ++i) {
        std::cout << '\n' << (i+1) <<"  Enter --> Last Name --> First Name --> Birt Month --> Birth Day --> Birth Year\n";
        std::cin >> sp[i];
    }
}


int main()
{
    // This is our player vector
    std::vector<sPlayer> players{};

    // Andf here a copy with the sorted data
    std::vector<sPlayer> playersSorted{};

    // If we want zo search a name in the vector
    std::string searchString{};
    bool playerFound{ false };

    // Menu selection
    int selection{ CmdExit };
    do {
        selection = getMenuSelection();
        switch (selection)
        {
        case CmdInputData:
            // Read player vector
            enterSPlayerData(players);
            break;

        case CmdDisplayOriginalData:
            // Show all players
            std::cout << "\n\nPlayer List\n\n";
            std::copy(players.begin(), players.end(), std::ostream_iterator<sPlayer>(std::cout, "\n"));
            break;

        case CmdSortByLastName:
            // Copy player list and sort the copy
            playersSorted.clear();
            std::copy(players.begin(), players.end(), std::back_inserter(playersSorted));
            std::sort(playersSorted.begin(), playersSorted.end(), 
                [](const sPlayer & sp1, const sPlayer & sp2) { return sp1.lname < sp2.lname; });
            break;

        case CmdDisplaySortedData:
            // Show the sorted data
            std::cout << "\n\nPlayer List Sorted\n\n";
            std::copy(playersSorted.begin(), playersSorted.end(), std::ostream_iterator<sPlayer>(std::cout, "\n"));
            break;

        case CmdSearchLastName:
            // Sear for a part of a name
            std::cout << "\n\nSearch Player name\n\nEnter some starting characters of Name:  ";
            std::cin >> searchString;
            playerFound = false;
            std::for_each(players.begin(), players.end(),
                [&searchString, &playerFound](const sPlayer & sp) {
                    if (sp.lname.find(searchString) != std::string::npos) {
                        std::cout << "Found Player\n" << sp << '\n';
                        playerFound = true;
                    }
                }
            );
            if (!playerFound) std::cout << "\nNo player found\n\n";
            break;
        default:
            selection = CmdExit;
            break;
        }
    } while (selection != CmdExit);
    return 0;
}
```